# Android, Two ImageViews transparency synchronize

Tags: android

There are two ImageViews.

I set a Bitmap image file on ImageView1.

and ImageView1 setalpha(50) to makes transparency.

If I drag and drop ImageView1 on a ImageView2 then,

How can ImageView2 show no-transparency where intersect part.

Answer (score 0):

- ImageView1.setAlpha(50)
- ImageView2.setAlpha(100)
- Create a third ImageView and set image to same color as background.
- ImageView2.setAlpha(~50?) manipulate that view's position relative to ImageView2.

For instance, if ImageView1 intersects ImageView2 at x=40 and ImageView2 is to the right. Simply set the ImageView3.left = 40, and then possibly manipulate the width from there if you need to.

Should work for simple purposes, and I think it's probably the most efficient/simple way to do something like this. By using the same color as the background, and overlaying the ImageView3, I believe it would give you the same effect as setting alpha on original picture.

As always could be wrong... let me know if you test though :-)